# I/O errors on SD-card

Tags: sd-card

recently I installed Ubuntu 16.04 on my Raspberry 2 Model B. 
Everything went well and I had no errors. Then I tried to install owncloud, but i hung forever. Then even Ubuntu was freezing and so I had to pull the power plug. After Ubuntu was starting next time, some applications wouldn't start at all and then no application started anymore. I shutdown Ubuntu and I got some I/O errors.

```
[32121.459344] Ext4-fs error (device mcblk0p2): ext4_find_entry:1457: inode #130051: comm dbus-deamon: reading directory lblock 0
[32121.459344] Ext4-fs (mcblk0p2): previous I/O error to superblock detected
```

The same error for comm (sessions) , comm avahl-deamon and comm (dom-seed)
actually the first time I shutdown Ubuntu, the whole screen was full of these errors.
[image]

I can't even open a terminal properly, also not with ctrl + Alt + F2. It seems that some debugs are running through and its also throwing I/O errors in an 
(e.g. mmcblk0: error -110 transferring data, sector 8151061)

The 32GB microsd card on which I have installed Ubuntu is about 1 Year old and I had Raspian installed previously. Unfortunately I didn't fully format the Card before I installed Ubuntu, maybe that was the mistake.

Do you think I can rescue the Ubuntu installation somehow? 
If not, what can I do so that this doesn't happen again? Formating the SD-card before re-installing Ubuntu?
Or better using a new SD-card altogether? 
Thanks in advance for your help.

***UPDATE***
apparently the SD-Card was faulty. I formatted the SD-card (slow format) but the error kept coming back even then. With a new SD-card I've not seen this error anymore

Comment: finally I was able to open a terminal and do a sudo touch /forcefsck but it only gave me the possibility to enter maintenenace mode after a reboot. apparently it didn't do a fs-check because I can't see any results and I'm not sure if I can do fsck /dev/sdaX  there

Comment: Just try a fsck in maintenance modw.

Comment: now I can't even open a terminal anymore. So I give up on this.
I'll test the SD-Card with H2testw and see whether it's still good or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pulling the plug ona Raspberry Pi that isn't shutdown through software first has a high likelyhood of corrupting the SD card. Reformat and reinstall is your best option to fix this, learn how to interrupt a program when it hangs is your best option to prevent this from re-occuring (CTRL-C, CTRL-X, CTRL-Z, open another console (CTRL-ALT-F2) and run htop to kill the relevant processes).

Comment: I had to "hard" shutdown a computer many, many times before and and a corrupt file system resulted in far less then 1% of the cases. 
But I agree with you that other options should be tried first. Thanks for your hints on this.
I tested the SD-Card with H2testw and there was an error found. Then I formated the SD-Card and did a test with H2testw again and no errors where found anymore.  
So I hope this was it with the SD-Card and I give it another, last chance. 
And I'll do more often a backup-image of the Card... :-)
Thanks tlhlngan and ott for your help.

Comment: @Hermann- Computers running on hardrives are one thing, microcontrollers running on SD cards are another entirely. :)

Comment: Ok, I didn't know that. I will make sure to remember it. thx.